# Get all the direct Children of a specified Parent

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method called GetMenuItems which returns Heirarchical results. Here is the implementation:

```
public static ObservableCollection<MenuItem> GetMenuItems()
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(DirectoryPaths.DataDirectory_General + "MenuItems.xml");
    return LoadMenuItems(xDoc.Descendants("MenuItem"));
}

private static ObservableCollection<MenuItem> LoadMenuItems(IEnumerable<XElement> menuItems)
{
    return new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>(
        menuItems.Select(
            x => new MenuItem()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToDouble(x.Attribute("Id").Value),
                Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
                ImageData = x.Elements("ImageData").Any() ? x.Element("ImageData").Value : "",
                Angle = x.Elements("Angle").Any() ? Convert.ToDouble(x.Element("Angle").Value) : 0,
                ScaleX = x.Elements("ScaleX").Any() ? Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("ScaleX").Value) : 0,
                ScaleY = x.Elements("ScaleY").Any() ? Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("ScaleY").Value) : 0,
                ShortcutKey = x.Elements("ShortcutKey").Any() ? x.Element("ShortcutKey").Value : "",
                Background = x.Elements("Background").Any() ? x.Element("Background").Value : "#FF000000",
                MouseOver = x.Elements("MouseOver").Any() ? x.Element("MouseOver").Value : "#FF696969",
                menuItem = x.Elements("MenuItem").Any() ? LoadMenuItems(x.Elements("MenuItem")) : null
            }

        )

     );

}
```

Now I want to get all the direct children of a specific Parent.

To make it more clear let me give an example:

Suppose I want to get all the direct children MenuItems of MenuItem whose `Id = 1`.

Please note that I need to use GetMenuItems() method as I am not allowed to access those XML Files.

Comment: So is `menuItem` the collection of children? (That's an unconventional name, and it's actually pretty unhelpful that it uses `null` rather than an empty collection to represent a lack of children...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes menuItem is a collection of children and how can I have an empty collection?

Comment: I'll add that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your task into two parts:

- Finding the menu with a particular ID
- Getting its children

The latter is simple - you just use the `menuItem` property, which would be better named `Children` or something similar.

I'd tackle the first part by recursion - after making one important change. Instead of the `Children` property being null if there are no elements, just let it be an empty collection:

```
Children = LoadMenuItems(x.Elements("MenuItem")
```

That way, you can check all the children very easily, even if there aren't any - without any nullity checks. Generally, it's easier to represent a lack of items as an empty collection rather than a null reference.

So, to recursively find a menu item by ID, I'd use:

```
// TODO: Change the ID type from double to almost anything else. double is a
// *terrible* type to use for IDs.
public MenuItem FindMenuItemById(MenuItem item, double id)
{
    return item.Id == id ? item : item.Children
                                      .Select(x => FindMenuItemById(x, id))
                                      .Where(found => found != null)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

That will return `null` if there's no such menu item. Then you can just use:

```
if (item != null)
{
    var children = item.Children;
    ...
}
```

As an aside, your other properties can be converted much more simply using the conversion operators on `XElement` and the null-coalescing operator

```
// Again, change this! Don't use double!
Id = (double) x.Attribute("Id"),
Name = (string) x.Element("Name"),
ImageData = (string) x.Element("ImageData") ?? "",
Angle = (double?) x.Element("Angle") ?? 0d,
ScaleX = (double?) x.Element("ScaleX") ?? 0d,
ScaleY = (double?) x.Element("ScaleY") ?? 0d,
ShortcutKey = (string) x.Element("ShortcutKey") ?? "",
Background = (string) x.Element("Background") ?? "#FF000000",
MouseOver = (string) x.Element("MouseOver") ?? "#FF696969",
```

Comment: Great Answer. Still I would like to ask 2 questions. 1) Why should I not use double Data-Type for Id. I am asking this because I have Hierarchical structure in XML File and so My Ids are 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3,3.1.......... 2) If I want to get just the Top Level Items then what should I do? And thanks for helping.

Comment: @Vishal: For the double part, think about this - what does the 10th child of item 3 look like? I suspect it's "3.10", which is the same value as "3.1". Fundamentally, menu item IDs simply *aren't* fractional numbers. I suggest you just use strings instead. For getting top level items - well, that's what `GetMenuItems()` gives you, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I understand the use of double is dangerous and I would like to use strings. And 2) GetMenuItems() returns all the Items including children. I don't want to have any children.

Comment: @Vishal: Ah, I'd missed the use of `Descendants`. That's the problem - use `Elements` instead, after you've found the parent node - I don't know what the XML looks like, so I don't know exactly what it would look like. It might be `xDoc.Root.Elements("MenuItem")` for example.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly now. I changed `xDoc.Descendents("MenuItem")` in `GetMenuItems` method to `xDoc.Element("MenuItem").Elements("MenuItems")`